# Only Https Post requests failing with cloudfront and ec2 instance running nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running a nodejs server on ec2 on port 3000. In order to connect it to internet, I am running a nginx server to proxy requests from port 80 to 3000.

I have a ec2 domain "http://ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com" and I am able to make both post and get requests here successfully.

Now I have a domain and want "api.mydomain.com" to point to this server. For that I am using ACM and Cloudfront, after configuring both of them I am successfully able to make GET requests over https however post requests keep getting 502 error response from cloudfront.

This is how a request looks like:

(https) -> route53 -> cloudfront -> (http) -> nginx -> nodejs

- GET request on http://ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com: working
- POST request on http://ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com: working
- GET request on http://dyyyyy.cloudfront.net: working
- POST request on http://dyyyyy.cloudfront.net: working

However,

- GET request on https://dyyyyy.cloudfront.net: working
- POST request on https://dyyyyy.cloudfront.net: not working [<- how do I debug this]
- GET request on https://api.mydomain.com: working
- POST request on https://api.mydomain.com: not working

This is the my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  ec2-3-109-166-206.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:3000/ /;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
       }
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why are GET requests over https successful but POST requests give this error

```
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>502 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
```

Update: Adding Cloudfront Settings

1. Settings
2. price class: Use all edge locations (best performance)
3. Alternate domain name (CNAME): api.mydomain.com
4. Custom SSL certificate: domain.com (id generated by acm)
5. legacy client support: not enabled
6. security policy: TLSv1
7. Supported HTTP versions: HTTP1, HTTP2, HTTP3
8. Standard Logging: Off
9. IPv6: On

Origin:

1. domain: ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
2. protocol: match-viewer
3. http: 80
4. https: 443
5. Minimum Origin SSL protocol: TLSv1.2
6. origin path: [empty]
7. enable shield: No

Behavior

1. Path Pattern: default(*)
2. origin: ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
3. compress objects automatically: yes
4. viewer protocol policy: Http and Https
5. Allowed http methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
6. Restrict Viewer Access: No
7. Cache key and origin requests: Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)
8. Cache Policy: CachingOptimized
9. Origin Request Policy: None
10. Response Headers Policy: CorsAndSecurityHeadersPolicy
11. SmoothStream: No
12. Field Encryption: No
13. Function Associations: No Association (for all requests and responses)

Comment: Show your CloudFront settings.

Comment: Updated the question @AlexD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured 'protocol: match-viewer' in your CloudFront configuration.  This setting means that CloudFront uses HTTPS to connect to your origin server (EC2) when a client uses HTTPS to connect to `api.mydomain.com` but your `nginx` doesn't have HTTPS configured. Switch to protocol to HTTP-only or configure HTTPS in `nginx`. Reference: [CloudFront documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy)